# Issues Installing Ubuntu to my Desktop

Tags: system-installation

I am having issues installing Ubuntu onto my Windows 7 Desktop. I have tried using a USB and using UNetbootin to do it from my SSD. I tried using Etcher after reading another question with similar issues as well. Neither have worked so far. When I select it in the boot up selection it says there is nothing there or that the decoding failed. Am I missing something or could it be an issue with my system? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear regarding what issue/error you are facing. Please elaborate what do you mean by this - When I select it in the boot up selection it says there is nothing there or that the decoding failed.Add these info in your question rather than writing them in comments

Comment: That is all that I know. If I select the UEFI USB, it takes me to the first selection screen where you choose Ubuntu, OEM Install, etc. But after I select Ubuntu or the OEM Install, it will tell me that it fails to decode and my screen goes blank. I barely had enough time to make out that much of what it says. After searching more, I am wondering if a graphics card affects it. I read some people were having issues with that.

Comment: Please edit to include the exact installation steps you are performing, and when you experience an erroneous or non-expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB menu >  Additional Options > Recovery Mode > Root Access

type the following commands. This will rebuild the broken ramdisk file.

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(uname -r)

reboot
```

Comment: And it works when trying to install? I looked around about GRUB but it was all on already installed systems.

Comment: Got it to work finally by using the safe graphics mode. I am still unsure why it would not work the othe ways.

Comment: @Reisbig2009 feel free to accept the answer if it helped